# Can't open sqlite DB from iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I'm relatively new to iOS development and it is my first time trying to use the `CoreData.framework`.

I created a very simple DB with "[sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)" and copied it into my project in XCode. I can see the file is included in the app bundle. I tried to access the DB in the `AppDelegate` class, following method:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    //For now using the `SQLite` store generate manually. Make sure to open the
    //store in read only mode since we cannot modify files in the bundle.

    NSURL *storeURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MatchWatcher" withExtension:@"sqlite"];
    //Should be like below
    NSDictionary *storeOptions = @{NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption:@YES, NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"} };
//    NSDictionary *storeOptions = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"} };
    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if(![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                              configuration:nil
                                                        URL:storeURL
                                                    options:storeOptions
                                                      error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

As you can see, I try to use the storeOptions variable that includes the ReadOnly opening of the DB, but this gives me the following exception:

> 2015-07-06 14:15:18.372 MatchWatcher[27495:3849154] CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/john/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F8C9B7DC-3C1D-495C-8FB6-80A9EA5976BB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CA64DE15-428B-4356-BB2B-066258E5FBAE/MatchWatcher.app/MatchWatcher.sqlite options:{
>       NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption = 1;
>       NSSQLitePragmasOption =     {
>           "journal_mode" = DELETE;
>       };
>       } ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 257.)" UserInfo=0x7fa38a73cbb0 {NSUnderlyingException=Cannot create a new database file with the read only option at path: /Users/john/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F8C9B7DC-3C1D-495C-8FB6-80A9EA5976BB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CA64DE15-428B-4356-BB2B-066258E5FBAE/MatchWatcher.app/MatchWatcher.sqlite} with userInfo dictionary {
>       NSUnderlyingException = "Cannot create a new database file with the read only option at path: /Users/john/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F8C9B7DC-3C1D-495C-8FB6-80A9EA5976BB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CA64DE15-428B-4356-BB2B-066258E5FBAE/MatchWatcher.app/MatchWatcher.sqlite";
>       }
>       2015-07-06 14:15:18.373 StockWatcher[27495:3849154] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 257.)" UserInfo=0x7fa38a73cbb0 {NSUnderlyingException=Cannot create a new database file with the read only option at path: /Users/john/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F8C9B7DC-3C1D-495C-8FB6-80A9EA5976BB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CA64DE15-428B-4356-BB2B-066258E5FBAE/MatchWatcher.app/MatchWatcher.sqlite}, {
>       NSUnderlyingException = "Cannot create a new database file with the read only option at path: /Users/john/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F8C9B7DC-3C1D-495C-8FB6-80A9EA5976BB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CA64DE15-428B-4356-BB2B-066258E5FBAE/MatchWatcher.app/MatchWatcher.sqlite";
>       }

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? Some help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: As the error messages says: You set the flag NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption, but want't to create (=write) a database

Comment: I really don't, I want to open an already existing DB file which is present in the bundle. Is there any specific content in the DB file that should be present in order to be able to open it with Xcode? The one I have right now is a very simple DB with 1 table that has 3 columns (2 varchars, and 1 float).

Comment: CoreData isn't just a simple sqlite database. It creates tables with specific names. If you really want to use CoreData, the best way would be to let CoreData create the table once and you edit that created database. If you only want to use your own sqlite database, you don't have to use CoreData. There exist (very raw) C functions to read and write sqlite databases (see "sqlite3.h"), but also Wrapper classes (for example https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), so you don't have to write C code.

Comment: @freytag , this helps, I'll try to create the DB using a helper OS X add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite file that Core Data uses is structured in a closed way.  It is not meant to be used against a SQLite file that you have developed outside of Core Data.

Core Data is designed to be the model of your application.  Treating it as a relational database tool will cause you issues.  Use it as the model of your application and then let it persist to disk.  Not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks Marcus your answer is similar to that of @freytag and I will create the DB using a helper OS X app.